# Stored Video Analysis takes too long

Tags: amazon-rekognition

I am using the amazon rekognition API to analyse my video to find and Search faces.
A one minute video has been on processing for nearly an hour now. But have not received any result .
Is this normal ?

Answer (score 0):

SNS needed to be connected With SQN

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-sqs-as-subscriber.html#SendMessageToSQS.sqs.permissions